# How do I know if a Riemann sum is an over or under approximation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

This was something I understood when we first went over it in class, but my text doesn't really cover it and I cannot find a direct answer online:

If I use, say, the midpoint rule on a contour map to get the approximate value of an integral how can I determine if it is an over-approx. or under-approx.?

Thanks!

**I should clarify that I am working with contour maps and double integrals- not single integrals.**